# What to do when in-text citations are not returning ordered numbers (one not appearing correctly)?

Tags: bibtex, citing, miktex, multiple-citations

I have the following Bibtex. It does not compile and I don't know why and the culprit of disorder in the latex file is @article{YANG2019109359 it is appearing as 4 while it should appear as 3 when cited.Please ignore the first parts since they are provided by the provider, my entries are where the bibtex of mine (aka references) starts

What to do?

thx in advance code:

```
% First the Full Name is given, then the abbreviation used in the AMS Math
% Reviews, with an indication if it could not be found there.
% Note the 2nd overwrites the 1st, so swap them if you want the full name.

 %{AMS}
 @String{AMSTrans = "American Mathematical Society Translations" }
 @String{AMSTrans = "Amer. Math. Soc. Transl." }
 @String{BullAMS = "Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society" }
 @String{BullAMS = "Bull. Amer. Math. Soc." }
 @String{ProcAMS = "Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society" }
 @String{ProcAMS = "Proc. Amer. Math. Soc." }
 @String{TransAMS = "Transactions of the American Mathematical Society" }
 @String{TransAMS = "Trans. Amer. Math. Soc." }

 %ACM
 @String{CACM = "Communications of the {ACM}" }
 @String{CACM = "Commun. {ACM}" }
 @String{CompServ = "Comput. Surveys" }
 @String{JACM = "J. ACM" }
 @String{ACMMathSoft = "{ACM} Transactions on Mathematical Software" }
 @String{ACMMathSoft = "{ACM} Trans. Math. Software" }
 @String{SIGNUM = "{ACM} {SIGNUM} Newsletter" }
 @String{SIGNUM = "{ACM} {SIGNUM} Newslett." }

 @String{AmerSocio = "American Journal of Sociology" }
 @String{AmerStatAssoc = "Journal of the American Statistical Association" }
 @String{AmerStatAssoc = "J. Amer. Statist. Assoc." }
 @String{ApplMathComp = "Applied Mathematics and Computation" }
 @String{ApplMathComp = "Appl. Math. Comput." }
 @String{AmerMathMonthly = "American Mathematical Monthly" }
 @String{AmerMathMonthly = "Amer. Math. Monthly" }
 @String{BIT = "{BIT}" }
 @String{BritStatPsych = "British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical
          Psychology" }
 @String{BritStatPsych = "Brit. J. Math. Statist. Psych." }
 @String{CanMathBull = "Canadian Mathematical Bulletin" }
 @String{CanMathBull = "Canad. Math. Bull." }
 @String{CompApplMath = "Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics" }
 @String{CompApplMath = "J. Comput. Appl. Math." }
 @String{CompPhys = "Journal of Computational Physics" }
 @String{CompPhys = "J. Comput. Phys." }
 @String{CompStruct = "Computers and Structures" }
 @String{CompStruct = "Comput. \& Structures" }
 @String{CompJour = "The Computer Journal" }
 @String{CompJour = "Comput. J." }
 @String{CompSysSci = "Journal of Computer and System Sciences" }
 @String{CompSysSci = "J. Comput. System Sci." }
 @String{Computing = "Computing" }
 @String{ContempMath = "Contemporary Mathematics" }
 @String{ContempMath = "Contemp. Math." }
 @String{Crelle = "Crelle's Journal" }
 @String{GiornaleMath = "Giornale di Mathematiche" }
 @String{GiornaleMath = "Giorn. Mat." } % didn't find in AMS MR., ibid.

 %IEEE
 @String{Computer = "{IEEE} Computer" }
 @String{IEEETransComp = "{IEEE} Transactions on Computers" }
 @String{IEEETransComp = "{IEEE} Trans. Comput." }
 @String{IEEETransAC = "{IEEE} Transactions on Automatic Control" }
 @String{IEEETransAC = "{IEEE} Trans. Automat. Control" }
 @String{IEEESpec = "{IEEE} Spectrum" } % didn't find in AMS MR
 @String{ProcIEEE = "Proceedings of the {IEEE}" }
 @String{ProcIEEE = "Proc. {IEEE}" } % didn't find in AMS MR
 @String{IEEETransAeroElec = "{IEEE} Transactions on Aerospace and Electronic
     Systems" }
 @String{IEEETransAeroElec = "{IEEE} Trans. Aerospace Electron. Systems" }

 @String{IMANumerAna = "{IMA} Journal of Numerical Analysis" }
 @String{IMANumerAna = "{IMA} J. Numer. Anal." }
 @String{InfProcLet = "Information Processing Letters" }
 @String{InfProcLet = "Inform. Process. Lett." }
 @String{InstMathApp = "Journal of the Institute of Mathematics and
     its Applications" }
 @String{InstMathApp = "J. Inst. Math. Appl." }
 @String{IntControl = "International Journal of Control" }
 @String{IntControl = "Internat. J. Control" }
 @String{IntNumerEng = "International Journal for Numerical Methods in
     Engineering" }
 @String{IntNumerEng = "Internat. J. Numer. Methods Engrg." }
 @String{IntSuper = "International Journal of Supercomputing Applications" }
 @String{IntSuper = "Internat. J. Supercomputing Applic." } % didn't find
%% in AMS MR
 @String{Kibernetika = "Kibernetika" }
 @String{JResNatBurStand = "Journal of Research of the National Bureau
     of Standards" }
 @String{JResNatBurStand = "J. Res. Nat. Bur. Standards" }
 @String{LinAlgApp = "Linear Algebra and its Applications" }
 @String{LinAlgApp = "Linear Algebra Appl." }
 @String{MathAnaAppl = "Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications" }
 @String{MathAnaAppl = "J. Math. Anal. Appl." }
 @String{MathAnnalen = "Mathematische Annalen" }
 @String{MathAnnalen = "Math. Ann." }
 @String{MathPhys = "Journal of Mathematical Physics" }
 @String{MathPhys = "J. Math. Phys." }
 @String{MathComp = "Mathematics of Computation" }
 @String{MathComp = "Math. Comp." }
 @String{MathScand = "Mathematica Scandinavica" }
 @String{MathScand = "Math. Scand." }
 @String{TablesAidsComp = "Mathematical Tables and Other Aids to Computation" }
 @String{TablesAidsComp = "Math. Tables Aids Comput." }
 @String{NumerMath = "Numerische Mathematik" }
 @String{NumerMath = "Numer. Math." }
 @String{PacificMath = "Pacific Journal of Mathematics" }
 @String{PacificMath = "Pacific J. Math." }
 @String{ParDistComp = "Journal of Parallel and Distributed Computing" }
 @String{ParDistComp = "J. Parallel and Distrib. Comput." } % didn't find
%% in AMS MR
 @String{ParComputing = "Parallel Computing" }
 @String{ParComputing = "Parallel Comput." }
 @String{PhilMag = "Philosophical Magazine" }
 @String{PhilMag = "Philos. Mag." }
 @String{ProcNAS = "Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences
                    of the USA" }
 @String{ProcNAS = "Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U. S. A." }
 @String{Psychometrika = "Psychometrika" }
 @String{QuartMath = "Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, Oxford, Series (2)" }
 @String{QuartMath = "Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2)" }
 @String{QuartApplMath = "Quarterly of Applied Mathematics" }
 @String{QuartApplMath = "Quart. Appl. Math." }
 @String{RevueInstStat = "Review of the International Statisical Institute" }
 @String{RevueInstStat = "Rev. Inst. Internat. Statist." }

 %SIAM
 @String{JSIAM = "Journal of the Society for Industrial and Applied
     Mathematics" }
 @String{JSIAM = "J. Soc. Indust. Appl. Math." }
 @String{JSIAMB = "Journal of the Society for Industrial and Applied
     Mathematics, Series B, Numerical Analysis" }
 @String{JSIAMB = "J. Soc. Indust. Appl. Math. Ser. B Numer. Anal." }
 @String{SIAMAlgMeth = "{SIAM} Journal on Algebraic and Discrete Methods" }
 @String{SIAMAlgMeth = "{SIAM} J. Algebraic Discrete Methods" }
 @String{SIAMAppMath = "{SIAM} Journal on Applied Mathematics" }
 @String{SIAMAppMath = "{SIAM} J. Appl. Math." }
 @String{SIAMComp = "{SIAM} Journal on Computing" }
 @String{SIAMComp = "{SIAM} J. Comput." }
 @String{SIAMMatrix = "{SIAM} Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications" }
 @String{SIAMMatrix = "{SIAM} J. Matrix Anal. Appl." }
 @String{SIAMNumAnal = "{SIAM} Journal on Numerical Analysis" }
 @String{SIAMNumAnal = "{SIAM} J. Numer. Anal." }
 @String{SIAMReview = "{SIAM} Review" }
 @String{SIAMReview = "{SIAM} Rev." }
 @String{SIAMSciStat = "{SIAM} Journal on Scientific and Statistical
     Computing" }
 @String{SIAMSciStat = "{SIAM} J. Sci. Statist. Comput." }

 @String{SoftPracExp = "Software Practice and Experience" }
 @String{SoftPracExp = "Software Prac. Experience" } % didn't find in AMS MR
 @String{StatScience = "Statistical Science" }
 @String{StatScience = "Statist. Sci." }
 @String{Techno = "Technometrics" }
 @String{USSRCompMathPhys = "{USSR} Computational Mathematics and Mathematical
     Physics" }
 @String{USSRCompMathPhys = "{U. S. S. R.} Comput. Math. and Math. Phys." }
 @String{VLSICompSys = "Journal of {VLSI} and Computer Systems" }
 @String{VLSICompSys = "J. {VLSI} Comput. Syst." }
 @String{ZAngewMathMech = "Zeitschrift fur Angewandte Mathematik und
     Mechanik" }
 @String{ZAngewMathMech = "Z. Angew. Math. Mech." }
 @String{ZAngewMathPhys = "Zeitschrift fur Angewandte Mathematik und Physik" }
 @String{ZAngewMathPhys = "Z. Angew. Math. Phys." }

% Publishers % ================================================= |

 @String{Academic = "Academic Press" }
 @String{ACMPress = "{ACM} Press" }
 @String{AdamHilger = "Adam Hilger" }
 @String{AddisonWesley = "Addison-Wesley" }
 @String{AllynBacon = "Allyn and Bacon" }
 @String{AMS = "American Mathematical Society" }
 @String{Birkhauser = "Birkha{\"u}ser" }
 @String{CambridgePress = "Cambridge University Press" }
 @String{Chelsea = "Chelsea" }
 @String{ClaredonPress = "Claredon Press" }
 @String{DoverPub = "Dover Publications" }
 @String{Eyolles = "Eyolles" }
 @String{HoltRinehartWinston = "Holt, Rinehart and Winston" }
 @String{Interscience = "Interscience" }
 @String{JohnsHopkinsPress = "The Johns Hopkins University Press" }
 @String{JohnWileySons = "John Wiley and Sons" }
 @String{Macmillan = "Macmillan" }
 @String{MathWorks = "The Math Works Inc." }
 @String{McGrawHill = "McGraw-Hill" }
 @String{NatBurStd = "National Bureau of Standards" }
 @String{NorthHolland = "North-Holland" }
 @String{OxfordPress = "Oxford University Press" }  %address Oxford or London?
 @String{PergamonPress = "Pergamon Press" }
 @String{PlenumPress = "Plenum Press" }
 @String{PrenticeHall = "Prentice-Hall" }
 @String{SIAMPub = "{SIAM} Publications" }
 @String{Springer = "Springer-Verlag" }
 @String{TexasPress = "University of Texas Press" }
 @String{VanNostrand = "Van Nostrand" }
 @String{WHFreeman = "W. H. Freeman and Co." }

%Entries
\emergencystretch=1em

\raggedbottom

%our articles







@MANUAL{CDC,
  title =        {COVID-19 Employer Information for Office Buildings},
  author =       {Centers for Disease Control and Prevention},
  month =        {Sep},
  year =         2020,
  note =         {https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/community/office-buildings.html}
}

@article{doi:10.1080/09613218.2020.1760775,
author = {Sara Gilani and William O’Brien},
title = {Natural ventilation usability under climate change in Canada and the United States},
journal = {Building Research \& Information},
volume = {0},
number = {0},
pages = {1-20},
year  = {2020},
publisher = {Routledge},
doi = {10.1080/09613218.2020.1760775},

URL = { 
        https://doi.org/10.1080/09613218.2020.1760775
    
},
eprint = { 
        https://doi.org/10.1080/09613218.2020.1760775
    
}

}

@article{YANG2019109359,
title = "A review of advanced air distribution methods - theory, practice, limitations and solutions",
journal = "Energy and Buildings",
volume = "202",
pages = "109359",
year = "2019",
issn = "0378-7788",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.enbuild.2019.109359",
url = "%http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378778819307893",
author = "B. Yang and A.K. Melikov and A. Kabanshi and C. Zhang and F.S. Bauman and G. Cao and H. Awbi and H. Wigö and J. Niu and K.W.D. Cheong and K.W. Tham and M. Sandberg and P.V. Nielsen and R. Kosonen and R. Yao and S. Kato and S.C. Sekhar and S. Schiavon and T. Karimipanah and X. Li and Z. Lin",
keywords = "Fully mixing ventilation, Non-uniform ventilation, Air distribution, Thermal comfort, Air quality, Energy efficiency",
abstract = "%Ventilation and air distribution methods are important for indoor thermal environments and air quality. Effective distribution of airflow for indoor built environments with the aim of simultaneously offsetting thermal and ventilation loads in an energy efficient manner has been the research focus in the past several decades. Based on airflow characteristics, ventilation methods can be categorized as fully mixed or non-uniform. Non-uniform methods can be further divided into piston, stratified and task zone ventilation. In this paper, the theory, performance, practical applications, limitations and solutions pertaining to ventilation and air distribution methods are critically reviewed. Since many ventilation methods are buoyancy driving that confines their use for heating mode, some methods suitable for heating are discussed. Furthermore, measuring and evaluating methods for ventilation and air distribution are also discussed to give a comprehensive framework of the review."
}

@Book{Psy,
  author =       "The American Society of Heating, Refrigerating and Air-Conditioning Engineers",
  year =         "2017",
  title =        "The 2017 ASHRAE Handbook—Fundamentals",
  series =       "",
  volume =       "",
  address =      "",
  publisher =    "",
  doi =          "",
  url =          "https://www.ashrae.org/technical-resources/ashrae-handbook/description-2017-ashrae-handbook-fundamentals",
  editor =       "",
  number =       "",
  month =        "",
  note =         "",
}
```

> So here is the file for MiKTeX:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{6.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.5pt}% 50% of original values
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%
%% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}


\acmConference[Woodstock '18]{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural
  Gaze Detection}{June 03--05, 2018}{Woodstock, NY}
\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection,
  June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-XXXX-X/18/06}





\begin{document}

%%
%% The "title" command has an optional parameter,
%% allowing the author to define a "short title" to be used in page headers.
\title{sample}

%%
%% The "author" command and its associated commands are used to define
%% the authors and their affiliations.
%% Of note is the shared affiliation of the first two authors, and the
%% "authornote" and "authornotemark" commands
%% used to denote shared contribution to the research.
\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\authornotemark[1]
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
  \country{USA}
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}

\author{Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}
  \streetaddress{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}
  \city{Hekla}
  \country{Iceland}}
\email{larst@affiliation.org}

\author{Valerie B\'eranger}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Inria Paris-Rocquencourt}
  \city{Rocquencourt}
  \country{France}
}

\author{Aparna Patel}
\affiliation{%
 \institution{Rajiv Gandhi University}
 \streetaddress{Rono-Hills}
 \city{Doimukh}
 \state{Arunachal Pradesh}
 \country{India}}

\author{Huifen Chan}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Tsinghua University}
  \streetaddress{30 Shuangqing Rd}
  \city{Haidian Qu}
  \state{Beijing Shi}
  \country{China}}

\author{Charles Palmer}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Palmer Research Laboratories}
  \streetaddress{8600 Datapoint Drive}
  \city{San Antonio}
  \state{Texas}
  \country{USA}
  \postcode{78229}}
\email{cpalmer@prl.com}

\author{John Smith}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}
  \streetaddress{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}
  \city{Hekla}
  \country{Iceland}}
\email{jsmith@affiliation.org}

\author{Julius P. Kumquat}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{The Kumquat Consortium}
  \city{New York}
  \country{USA}}
\email{jpkumquat@consortium.net}

%%
%% By default, the full list of authors will be used in the page
%% headers. Often, this list is too long, and will overlap
%% other information printed in the page headers. This command allows
%% the author to define a more concise list
%% of authors' names for this purpose.
\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}

%%
%% The abstract is a short summary of the work to be presented in the
%% article.
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

%%
%% The code below is generated by the tool at http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm.
%% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below.
%%
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010405.10010432.10010439</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Applied computing~Engineering</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Applied computing~Engineering}

%%
%% Keywords. The author(s) should pick words that accurately describe
%% the work being presented. Separate the keywords with commas.
\keywords{}

%% A "teaser" image appears between the author and affiliation
%% information and the body of the document, and typically spans the
%% page.


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
AAA \cite{CDC}. AAA \cite{YANG2019109359, doi:10.1080/09613218.2020.1760775}. 


    
    \section{Computation Methods}
     ASHRAE \cite{Psy}. 



%%
%% The acknowledgments section is defined using the "acks" environment
%% (and NOT an unnumbered section). This ensures the proper
%% identification of the section in the article metadata, and the
%% consistent spelling of the heading.
\begin{acks}

\end{acks}

%%
%% The next two lines define the bibliography style to be used, and
%% the bibliography file.
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base}
```

Comment: The number assigned (3 or 4) depends on the tex document and the sort order specified in the bibtex style about which you have given no indication. you have tex commands `\emergencystretch=1em

\raggedbottom`  in the bib file which should be removed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you David, I removed my text from Miketex file and I have added the code. I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at it. I also removed those two but didn't help.

Comment: if you use unsrt (so numbered in citation order) you get 3  if you use plain bib style (or apparently the acm one) you get 4 which is alphabetic order but with these entries without real author names I'm not exactly sure which keys it is sorting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you David but I am really new to this and I don't know what you meant. The references are real names and real references. So, what can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: `author =       "The American Society of Heating, Refrigerating and Air-Conditioning Engineers",`   is marking up a person like "Carlisle, David"  that is family name `The American Society of Heating`  Given name `Refrigerating and Air-Conditioning Engineers`  so if you sort entries into alphabetic order of authors the result will be   somewhat odd.

Comment: test with changing the bib style to `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`  and see the keys that are generated from the author names given.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess I need to contact them since the references are being arranged based on alphabets and then numbered (while they are numbered), maybe it's something they really want

Comment: If they told you to use that specific bibtex style that is presumably what they want, but you should fix the author markup, eg put a {} around it to hide the comma